Tate conjecture for singular varieties in terms of intersection homology
In his book “Mixed motives and algebraic K-theory”, Jannsen generalizes the Tate conjecture to a potentially singular projective variety $X$ over a finitely generated field. The statement is the same as the usual statement of the Tate conjecture, except in the absence of Poincare duality one must construe the cycle class map as landing in $\ell$-adic homology, rather than cohomology. I am trying to understand how the cycle class map interacts with the intersection (co)homology of $X$. Can one state the Tate conjecture for $X$ in terms of intersection homology? It would be almost as good to instead consider the same setup over $\mathbb{C}$ and the Hodge conjecture instead of the Tate conjecture.

I've thought about it briefly, and this is what I came up with: I claim that there is a cycle class $[Z]\in IH^{2p}(X) = H^{2p}(X, j_{!*}Q_\ell[\dim X])$ for a codimension $p$ cycle not supported in the singular locus. To define it, apply the decomposition to a resolution/nonsingular alteration etc. etc. I wasn't able to convince mysef that all Hodge/Tate  cycles should arise this way, however.

@DonuArapura theorem 1 of this paper seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605603

Great thanks. Will take a look.
